# Code Igniter Active Record - Num Rows & Results

Tags: codeigniter

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')->from($this->table)->order_by($sql);
```

The CI documentation isn't clear about this and I'm not entirely sure how this should work... if I have this query and need to check the num_rows() AND get results in an array.  How would I do that?

When I use `$this->db->select('*')->from($this->table)->order_by($sql)->get();` I'm not able to check num_rows()

Ideally I'd use result_array() to get the results in an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this

```
$query = $this->db->order_by('column name')->get('your tablename');

//note that your result must be an object

$count = $query->num_rows();//your num rows result handler

$result = $query->result_array();//your query result
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the function in your model to this:

```
function your_function()

{

    $this->db->select('*, COUNT(*) as count');
    $this->db->order_by($sql);
    $query = $this->db->get('table');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)

    {

        return $query->result();

    }

}
```

Pass the data from your controller to your view.

```
    $data['data'] = $this->your_model->your_function();
```

And then you can display it just like any other returned data.

```
    echo $data->count;
```

You might need to edit in a few bits and pieces like your table name, but that should do the trick.

: )

Answer (score 0):

better use:

```html
$result = $query->row();
$cnt = $result->count;
```

instead of result_array(); which gives you error.
Hope this helps!